# Function calling convention Powerpc vs Intel

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-trace, intel, powerpc

I need information on the following:

How powerpc and intel processors allocate stack when calling a function?
- On what basis is stack size determined in each case i.e powerpc and intel x86 processors
- Where are arguments and return addresses stored on stack.

Basically I need to stack layout in each case.

I have a situation where my program is crashing (segmentation fault) in intel machine and running fine on powerpc. I have found the cause of crash and the code snippet is below:

```
int function_a(int a)
{
   int local_var = 1;
   int ret_var;

   ret_var = function_b(&local_var);

}

int function_b (int* local_var_in_calld_fn)
{

   while (some_condition)
   {
      *local_var_in_calld_fn = some_computed_value; /* Cause of crash */
      local_var_in_calld_fn++; 
   }
   return something;
}
```

Some value is updated on an address which "may" be on stack and hence crashing.
The code exactly does not crash at location, but when debugged in gdb crashes somewhere outside after coming out of this function on x86 machine.

I am suspecting its corrupting the stack, but it is not crashing on powerpc.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using tools like Valgrind to identify your error?

Comment: I know about the tool, but I do not have it installed. Before I do that I need theory of how things happen on stack for my query :)

Answer (score 3):

There's an obvious stack overrun here.
`function_a` gets a pointer to a single `int`, increments (so it points somewhere else in the stack), and writes.

The outcome of a stack overrun is very unpredictable. It depends on calling conventions, but also on compiler decisions such as ordering of variables and inlining, which are not standardized in any way.

I wouldn't dwell on figuring out why it crashes in one case and not in another.
Better just fix it.

Answer (score 0):

*The OS is responsible for allocating the stack, not the processor.* The PowerPC processor doesn't even know or care about a stack; the "stack pointer" is by convention `r1`, a perfectly normal register, but this is platform-dependent. You haven't stated what platform this is running on.

In this case, the crash is caused by the line `local_var_in_calld_fn++;`, which is undefined behaviour (perhaps you mean `*local_var_in_calld_fn++;`). The question is then "Why doesn't undefined behaviour crash?" to which the answer is simple:

**Undefined behaviour is *undefined*, so *absolutely anything* can happen, including not crashing.**

That aside, the simplest explanation for why it doesn't crash is because `some_condition` evaluates to false on PPC (because it's single-core so there's less lock contention so you haven't noticed the crash yet).

I can also come up with a case where this does not crash:

- On this particular platform, stacks grow up (I'm not sure if any common ones do this). This means the write to `*local_var_in_calld_fn` effectively grows the stack and might clobber `function_b()`'s stack, but not the stack of any callers.
- `function_b()` is a "leaf function" (i.e. does not make any function calls) so LR does not need to be saved on the stack. This means writing to `*local_var_in_calld_fn` does not clobber the return address.
- `some_condition` becomes false soon enough that you don't run out of stack.